# Can you limit annotation target to be subclasses of a certain class?

Tags: java, validation, annotations

Can you limit that a target of an annotation must be of a certain class?

I want to create a new validation Constraint to limit file types that are uploaded. The constraint annotation must only go on a MultipartFile property, not on String or anything like that. How do I limit this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not at compile-time; the only restrictions available for annotation placement are by element type (method, class, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible (and was possible when the question was asked).

As a general rule, when working with annotations you need to use an annotation processor.  You can write an annotation processor that issues errors whenever an annotation is written in a disallowed location.

If your question is whether this is possible with plain `javac` and no annotation processor, then the answer is "no".

Comment: Can you give an example, or a link to the documentation, on how to set up a project that refuses to allow an annotation on the wrong type of object?  In my case, we have a common base class for our end-to-end tests (using Junit 5) that does mandatory cleanup.  When people forget to extend the base class, it causes problems that are hard to track down and debug.  Want to add something that, at least in the context of my project, refuses to run a test case whose class does not extend the base class.

Comment: An example annotation processor is the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/). It issues an `anno.on.irrelevant` error when an annotation is written on the wrong type. The test case [`AllowedTypes.java`](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/2f1f8165cf558ed9eb46fbbec817d74cee9a3cf2/checker/tests/regex/AllowedTypes.java) shows that [`@Regex`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/regex/qual/Regex.html) can be written on a `String`, `CharSequence`, `StringBuilder`, `Pattern`, `Matcher`, etc., but not on a `List`, `int`, `Integer`, etc.