# How to allow only classes annotated with some annotation in method parameters in Java?

Tags: java, annotations

Let's suppose I have annotation `@MyAnnotation` and two classes:

```
@MyAnnotation
class Foo {
}

class Bar {
}
```

and some method that needs class as parameter

```
someMethod(Class<?> klass)
```

Is it possible to restrict `someMethod` parameter only to classes that are annotated with `@MyAnnotation`? I mean:

```
someMethod(Foo.class) //Must work
someMethod(Bar.class) //Compiler error
```

If yes, how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24846206/can-you-limit-annotation-target-to-be-subclasses-of-a-certain-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

As a general rule, if a property is expressed using an annotation, you will need to use an annotation processor.

Here is a full example that uses the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/).

File `SO61029446.java`:

```
public class SO61029446 {
  void someMethod(Class<? extends @MyAnnotation Object> klass) {}

  void client() {
    someMethod(Foo.class); // Must work
    someMethod(Bar.class); // Compiler error
  }
}

@MyAnnotation
@SuppressWarnings("subtyping")
class Foo {}

class Bar {}
```

File `MyAnnotation.java`:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})
@SubtypeOf(UnknownMyAnnotation.class)
@interface MyAnnotation {}

@DefaultQualifierInHierarchy
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})
@SubtypeOf({})
@interface UnknownMyAnnotation {}
```

Now, run these commands (after installing the Checker Framework):

```
javacheck MyAnnotation.java
javacheck -g SO61029446.java -processor org.checkerframework.common.subtyping.SubtypingChecker -Aquals=MyAnnotation,UnknownMyAnnotation SO61029446.java
```

The output of the second command is:

```
SO61029446.java:11: error: [argument.type.incompatible] incompatible types in argument.
    someMethod(Bar.class); // Compiler error
                  ^
  found   : @UnknownMyAnnotation Class<@UnknownMyAnnotation Bar>
  required: @UnknownMyAnnotation Class<? extends @MyAnnotation Object>
```

The compiler has complained about the illegal invocation but has permitted the legal invocation, just as you requested.

A few notes:

- The `javacheck` command is as described in the [Checker Framework Manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/).
- There are two `javacheck` commands because the first one makes the annotations available on the classpath for the second one.
- The `@SuppressWarnings("subtyping")` annotation on the `Foo` class might not be needed, depending on your actual code.  (This is a toy example.)
- Slaw's answer starts with first sentence "No, this is not possible.", which is *incorrect*.  Slaw's different approach to solving the problem without annotations is not a bad one (in some ways it's better because it uses just the Java compiler without any additional tool), but it does not answer this question about using annotations.